# "QtCanvas3D is not installed" erron on qnx target

Tags: qt, qnx, qt3d

I have complied "frameBuffer" canvas3D example using Qnx kit and trying to run that executable on my Qnx target but it is throwing below error:

```
./framebuffer &

[1] 1216519
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QQnxScreen: QQNX_PHYSICAL_SCREEN_SIZE variable not set. Could not    determine physical screen size. Defaulting to 150x90.
qrc:/main.qml:39:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:40:1: module "QtQuick.Layouts" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:38:1: module "QtCanvas3D" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:39:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:40:1: module "QtQuick.Layouts" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:38:1: module "QtCanvas3D" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:39:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:40:1: module "QtQuick.Layouts" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:38:1: module "QtCanvas3D" is not installed
```

Can anyone suggests how to get installed these missing module. I am using Qt Crea tor 3.5.1(enterprise) licensed version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the path `QML2_IMPORT_PATH= "qml path"`,  which should be available in your QT installed folder.